# XUbuntu 20.04 can't open desktop launchers using double click

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, launcher, doubleclick

If I single or double click a desktop icon in Xubuntu 20.04 nothing happens (I get a pop-up showing what the launcher is as soon as I hover over the icon but it fails to launch). I have to right click and select 'Execute' to get the launcher to trigger.

Interestingly, if I switch to a 2nd user I have set up on the system, double click works fine.

I haven't used this pc in a while but I do not recall modifying any system settings related to mouse behavior. I can't find any settings that pertain to disabling left click.

Thanks for your assistance.